# What is the purpose of the CoreFoundation framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

I have been programming in Objective-C Cocoa for a little while using NSObjects etc.  I see that there is another framework: **CoreFoundation**.As i look it over, it seems to be a C-Style framework.

So I have some curiosities i'd like clarified. I've googled but found no direct answer.

1. What is the purpose of CoreFoundation framework?
2. Doesn't the Cocoa Framework provide every thing that's needed already?
3. Does the CoreFoundation Framework provide any advantages that the CocoaFramework does not provide?

These are some of the questions i have. If anyone can provide an answer, or provide me with resources to read about it, that would be great. I am wondering if its worth learning more about the framework.

Comment: I think it's pretty awesome not having to deal with 50+ obj-c/swift classes when you're just trying to test out a basic prompt 'hello world' from c or assembly language for example... or any day, really.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

History:  The Foundation dates to ~1993/1994 and the APIs therein were a part of the OpenStep APIs published by NeXT.

> What is the purpose of CoreFoundation framework?

CF was created during the transition of Mac OS to Mac OS X to help support that transition.  Initially, it was done both for speed and to allow purely non-Objective-C programs to be written.   Over time, that has proven to be a non-issue and CF has more and more bits that are implemented in Objective-C (have a look at the CoreFoundation binary using something like otool).

CFLite is a light-weight, portable, pure-C (IIRC) variant.

> Doesn't the Cocoa Framework provide every thing that's needed already?

More or less.   And, certainly moreso for building GUI applications on either iOS or OS X.

> Does the CoreFoundation Framework provide any advantages that the
>   CocoaFramework does not provide?

Several, but generally at a cost of decreased simplicity and increased fragility.

For example, the CF collections allow you to completely customize how memory is managed and objects are identified;  you can provide custom allocation/free/hashing/comparison hooks.  Through this, you can "easily" encapsulate non-Objective-C types in CF collections.

Comment: So, it sounds like although Core Foundation provides an API that can be called by pure C code, any executable you generate using Core Foundation includes your C code PLUS the Objective-C runtime library (libobjc.dylib), and operates (starts up, etc) as an Objective-C style executable with dynamically linked references.

Comment: There are two advantages in Core Foundation. objc_msgSend doesn't need to be called for method lookup. So the time spend looking up the method to execute is not required. The other one ties into this where the name of the function isn't passed along. Therefor it's harder for a hacker to probe your running app to see what's going on inside of it.

Comment: @Imakemymark Much of CoreFoundation is implemented by calling into Foundation using Objective-C, so, no, you aren't avoiding objc_msgSend().   As for hacking, using CoreFoundation isn't an impediment at all.   The symbols are all there and it is quite easy to read the assembly to see what bits of CF are being used.  See `stool -TtVv`.

Comment: That should be `otool`, not `stool`.   Dammed autocorrect wins again.

Answer (score 22):

CoreFoundation is more than just a C-based alternative to Foundation. In way over-simplified terms, Foundation essentially *is* CoreFoundation, since one is built on top of the other. Many of the classes in Foundation are just lightweight Objective C wrappers around their CoreFoundation counterpart, which is how toll-free bridging works (ex. CFString and NSString).

For more history, and a much more technical explanation, see [this article](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/bridge.html).

If you actually want to read the CoreFoundation source, several versions of Apple's "CFLite" framework are available for reference [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/).

Comment: +1 for the excellent link. but, i can't choose two answers. BBum answered the 3 concerns.

Comment: @user76859403 No problem, and go for bbum's answer. It's the best one.

Answer (score 4):

The Core Foundation framework provides the same functionality as the Foundation framework does but in C instead of Obj-C so that it can be used with C frameworks.

If you look around you will see that Apple has a few C frameworks like Core Graphics, Core Audio, Address book, etc.

Comment: Actually, CF has large chunks implemented in Objective-C and some of the APIs are wrappers around their Objective-C counterparts, not the other way around....